# How to put a default view for a tabview in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am new to iOS development. I want to put a default view for a tab bar. is it possible. If yes, can anyone give an example for it?

Here is what I mean by default view for a tab bar

```
|---------|
| default |
|  view   |
|---------|
| 1  | 2  | <- None of the tabs are selected
-----------

|----------|
| first    |
|  tab     |
| selected |
|----------|
| 1   | 2  |  <- first tab selected
------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, edited.  You should not and cannot display a UITabBar unselected.

Comment: I understand what you saying, But I need to know why its not possible Raj

Comment: It goes against the concepts of what a tab controller supports.  What happens once you select a tab?  You will never be able to go back to the "default view".  If you need this sort of behavior, try overlaying a custom UIView on top of the tab view and remove it once a user selects a tab.

Comment: try UITabBar.selectedItem = nil

Answer (score 0):

Create a default view as you want and add this as subview to first view controller in IB. Or if you want it by code write in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
      [self.view addSubView:defaultView];
}
```

and in your tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;  method add code like,

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
        [defaultView setHidden:YES];
}
```

This will hides your defaultView, when selected any tab item.